# how to disable screen recording in android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

In generally while we use java , we use the below code

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

to disable screen recording. How can we do this in Kotlin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for `kotlin`

```
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
```

and your need to import this **`import android.view.WindowManager`**

Answer (score -2):

yes .. I got the answer. just remove the semi colon at the end.
ie, change

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

to

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
```